# Collision with a hinged rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, collision

A rod of length 1m is hinged and a ball of mass m having velocity u collides and sticks to it(e=0).[image: Here is the img of the scenario]

My attempt: If we consider rod + ball as system then **about the hinge** there is no external impulse. Hence conserving angular momentum about the hinge.
Initial angular momentum = muL 
Final angular momentum=$ IW$ where I is moment of inertia of ball + rod  about the hinge after the collison hence I= $(\frac{ML^2}{3} + mL^2)W$ equating both sides we get w=5 which is not the answer given in my book. What went wrong???

Comment: No, the answer $\omega = 5$ is the correct answer. In fact, any way you approach this I get the same answer, together with the impulse $J=2.5\,\rm Ns$ and pin reaction impulse of $R=5 \,\rm Ns$.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thankyou so much for confirming, I am greatful.